# R: efficiently grep characters in rows of large data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of character strings that is >1M rows long:

```
>head(df)
     A    B     C     D
1   S1   S2    U1    U2
2   S1   S2    S2    S1
3   S2   S1    S1    S2
4   S1   M2    U1    S2
5   S1   S1    M2    M1
6   M2   M2    M1    M2
```

I would like to identify all rows where a particular character is present (e.g., "U").
The solutions I have found so far are working, but they are very slow, for example:

```
matches <- apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(x){ sum(grepl("U", x, perl=T)) > 0 })
```

Any idea how to improve this query?
Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the example data.frame to show that the aim is to identify elements in the data.frame that match the query but may not be strictly equal ("=="). This is why I was using grep in the first example. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: updates to address comments:

The following is also very fast (0.31 seconds, even faster than before):

```
rows <- which(
  rowSums(
    `dim<-`(grepl("U", as.matrix(df), fixed=TRUE), dim(df))
  ) > 0
)
```

And produces the same result as previous answers.  Using `fixed=FALSE` about doubles the time, but your example doesn't require that.

What we're doing here is cheating by applying `grepl` to a matrix, though really what we care about is turning `df` into a vector (which a matrix is), and `as.matrix` is one of the faster ways to do this.  Then we can just run one `grepl` command.  Finally, we use `dim<-` to turn the `grepl` vector result back into a matrix, and use `rowSums` to check which rows had matches.

Here are the reasons why this is much faster than your version:

- We call `grepl` once, instead of a million times as you do with `apply` since the function `apply` applies gets called once for each row; `grepl` is vectorized which means you want to minimize how many times you call it and take advantage of the vectorization
- We do the row match counts with `rowSums` instead of `apply`; `rowSums` is a much faster version of `apply(x, 1, sum)` (see docs for `?rowSums`).

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Here is a relatively straightforward solution that runs in 0.35 seconds on my system for a 1MM row by 4 column data frame:

```
rows <- which(rowSums(as.matrix(df) == "U") > 0)
```

To confirm

```
df[head(rows), ]
```

produces (every row has a U):

```
   a b c d
5  F B D U
8  R S U F
15 U L R P
20 U E E O
21 Y U D I
32 P F U H
```

And the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(
  `names<-`(
    replicate(4, sample(LETTERS, 1e6, rep=T), simplify=F),
    letters[1:4]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)

df = fread("~/Rscripts/SO.csv")  # fast read
x = df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x %like% "U")] # fast grep
y = x[, rowSums(x) > 0]
z = df[y,]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for the row index for characters, maybe try this.  It should be quite a bit faster than looping.

```
unique(row(df)[grep("U", unlist(df))])
# [1] 1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answered the original question, which was an exact match of characters in the matrix rather than a regular expression match]. Coerce to a matrix (which is the correct representation anyway??), compare each element to "U" (use `%in%` if there is more than one possible value of interest) to create a logical matrix, and compute the row sum; use that to subset the original

```
which(rowSums(as.matrix(df) == "U") > 0)
```

no need to explicitly loop (via apply or vapply); these are 'vectorized' calculations and fast (although the above implies creation of 2 new matrices, and so could be improved).